# svg line artifacts on different screen sizes

Tags: html, svg

I have issue for svg line coded with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" class="" > <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
</head>  
<body>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1412 900">
<g><line x1="150" y1="110" x2="1412" y2="110" stroke="#9ca4ab" stroke-
  width="2"></line></g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

As it shown on the screenshot: in the center of the line, line color changes.
This is only on some window sizes(4k for instance).
[image: svg line artifact picture]
Generally, it is different for different screen sizes

Comment: Could depend of color calibration of monitor.

Comment: And what happens when stroke width is more say - 6 ?

Comment: Maybe try shape-rendering: crispEdges

Comment: How the line looks will depend on where the line falls relative to the pixels of the screen.  And how thick it is after scaling.  A line with `stroke-width="1"` will look sharp if it falls exactly in the middle of a screen pixel.  But if it falls anywhere else - eg. 0.25 of the way across the pixel - then it will get anti-aliased over two pixels.  And will look wider and fainter.